# Replace a pattern in string only if a certain condition is satisfied - Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

how can we replace `'` with `\\'` in a string. (this can be done using `Regex.IsMatch(), Regex.Matches(), Regex.Replace()`
However, it should be done only if `'` doesn't have `\` or `\\` before already. (this is where I am stuck)

That means find all `'` which do not have `\` or `\\` before it and then add the same, i.e. `'` replace with `\\'`

Example string: `'abcd\'efg'hijkl'mno\\'pqrs'`

Resulting string: `\\'abcd\\'efg\\'hijkl\\'mno\\'pqrs\\'`

Comment: sorry for the confusion, just have updated the question with more details about what exactly I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need for regex, even.

```
var newStr = oldStr.Replace("\\'", "'").Replace("'", "\\'");
```

With regex, you can find all `'` that don't have `\\` before them with:

```
[^\\]'
```

Comment: Yours is smarter, I just went basic. He can group the `[]` and use it in the replacement string, so he doesn't lose that info. So it's not really incorrect.

Comment: Well, first, you must mean `[^\\\\]'` in order to escape the backslashes. And second, this only catches one backslash before, so it'd incorrectly catch `\'` which may have another meaning in his subject, leading to `\\\'`. And third, although minor, it would not catch a quote in the beginning of the subject (while the lookbehind would).

Comment: I wasn't sure if he meant \\ escaped or unescaped, so I just left it like that.

Comment: Oh, actually, great point; I missed that. Maybe he meant a single backslash. I take back some of my accusations of error.

Comment: @Yorye Nathan, @acheong87 Yes exactly, It should replace `'` with `\\'` at all places even at the first index and at the end index. Although, it should ignore if there is already present `\\` before.
On the other hand, if there is `\'` then it should also make it `\\'`.
So far, both the answers seems to be working at my end. I will test if for different combinations and conditions now. Thanks.

Comment: @Chetan They will both work. In general, you want to avoid Regex for simple cases like this, for performance sake.

Answer (score 5):

I think @YoryeNathan wins. But just to teach a regex lesson, this is exactly what *negative lookbehind assertions* exist for. Replace

```
(?<!\\\\)'
```

with

```
\\'
```

**Usage**

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<!\\\\)'", "\\'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, I was thinking something like `([^\\\\]')`, but this doesn't work for single-quote at beginning of the input.

Comment: You could use `($|[^\\\\]')` to deal with beginning :P

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit - Correct. Doing this without a negative lookbehind (for example in Javascript) would require a more complex expression: `(^|^.|.[^\\]|[^\\].)'`. In other words, four cases: (1) `'` as first character of string, (2) `'` as second character of string (since it can't possibly be \\\), (3) `'` following any character and a non-\ (since that excludes \\\), (4) `'` following a non-\ and any character (since that also excludes \\\).